# Order data from 2 tables by date

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have 3 tables: myMembers, forum_question and forum_answer.
myMembers:

```
id | usr ..|..| follow | ....
 1 | Bob . |..|3,2,....|.....
 2 | John  |..|1,8,5...|.....
 3 | ......|..|........The "follow" column store the data in an array of followers id.<p>
```

forum_question:

```
id | topic .| name  | idsender      | datetime
 1 | foo q .| Bob ..|.... 1........ | 07:20
 2 | foo1 q | Bob ..|.... 1........ | 07:10
 3 | foo2 q | John .|.... 2 ........| 06:00
```

forum_answer:

```
question_id | answer | a_name | idsender | datetime
 1 .........| answ 1 | Bob ...| 1 .......| 08:20
 2 ....... .| answ 2 | Bob ...| 1 .......| 07:20
 1 .........| answ 3 | John ..| 2 .......| 08:00
```

I have this:

```
$foll = mysql_query("SELECT follow FROM myMembers WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($foll)){
    $foll1 = explode(",", $row["follow"]);
                      }
foreach ($foll1 as $key => $value){
$displ = mysql_query("SELECT p.* FROM
(SELECT id, datetime, topic, name, idsender, 'question' AS TYPE FROM 
forum_question WHERE idsender = '$value' UNION
SELECT question_id, datetime, answer, a_name, idsender, 'answer' AS TYPE FROM
forum_answer  WHERE idsender = '$value')p
ORDER BY p.datetime DESC");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($displ)){
                $type= $row['TYPE'];
                $id = $row["id"];
                $topic = $row["topic"];
                $name = $row["a_name"];
                $idsender = $row["idsender"];
                $datetime=$row['datetime'];
echo '<div>'. $name .', '. $type .', '. $topic.', '. $datetime.'</div>'";
```

I have this output:

```
Bob, answer, answ1, 8:20
Bob, answer, answ2, 7:20
Bob, question, foo q, 7:20
Bob, question, foo1 q, 7:10
**John,** answer, answ 3, 8:00
**John,** question, foo2 q, 6:00
```

I want this output?

```
Bob, answer, answ1, 8:20
**John,** answer, answ3, 8:00
Bob, question, foo q, 7:20
Bob, answer, answ2, 7:20
Bob, question, foo1 q, 7:10
**John,** question, foo2 q, 6:00
```

It is possible?? Thanks !

Comment: Why not just `ORDER BY name` instead?

Comment: Adding ORDER BY datetime DESC would do the trick. I'm assuming you would like see rows from later posted ones to earlier posted ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by for a_name and order by datetime. So your query should be,

```
$displ = mysql_query("SELECT p.* FROM
(SELECT id, datetime, topic, name, idsender, 'question' AS TYPE FROM 
forum_question WHERE idsender = '$value' UNION
SELECT question_id, datetime, answer, a_name, idsender, 'answer' AS TYPE FROM
forum_answer  WHERE idsender = '$value')p
GROUP BY p.a_name ORDER BY p.datetime DESC")
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. If i use 'GROUP BY', the loop don't work. It shows me only a record from each user. What i want is to make a "follow system". I want to LIMIT last 10 entries in those 2 tables ORDER BY date. Grouping shows me 1 entry for each user in array even if i had posts with a recent date.

Comment: Can you please refer this link?
http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/joining-with-group-by-and-order-by.php

Comment: Remux can i have your mail id please? and you are from?

Comment: thats fine dude. Can i have your mail id so that we can have touch and do some knowledge transfer if need. or please invite me in gmail chat babuvino13@gmail.com